# Question about weak decay in p-p fusion

Tags: quantum-mechanics, astrophysics, fusion

I'm trying to write a very simple simulator of nuclear fusion (with very limited prior knowledge, as I'm finding out), and I'm having a very difficult time understanding p->n conversion.

I believe that the rarity of such a conversion is due to the different timescales of the interactions it can have.  One interaction is to emit a W<sup>+</sup> boson and become a deuteron, while the other (much more likely) outcome is to break apart again into two protons.

The question is: how can one calculate the chance of conversion?

Is it the ratio of how long a proton takes to convert to a neutron to how long a p-p pair remains fused before splitting apart?  Could these values be calculated and used to find the chances of any arbitrary nucleus experiencing quark conversion?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to calculate the conversion probability, but it's around $10^{-26}$. Note that the rest energy of a (non-virtual) W+ is ~80.4 GeV, over 80 times that of a proton or neutron.

Comment: It is not clear how you envisage this. From conservation of energy as the neutron is heavier than the proton there should be a reaction providing the energy to the protons which you do not include. are you thinking on these lines ? https://www.space.com/26956-proton-fusion-sun-power-source-infographic.html

Comment: This shows the balance of energies at the end of proton proton fusion in the sun https://energyeducation.ca/encyclopedia/Nuclear_fusion_in_the_Sun

Comment: @PM2Ring That's something I didn't even take into account.  I imagined that it emitted a W+ boson that decayed into positron + electron neutrino, but that's clearly not correct.  I guess it must just interact with the weak field through a virtual W+?

Comment: @annav I'm curious about that.  The important point is that a diproton (2xp) is *heavier* than a deuteron (p+n), with a mass difference of ~.9 MeV of energy (with ~.5 MeV released as a positron, and most of the rest as the electron neutrino).  Is it possible that the virtual W+ interacts with the over-stressed gluons or photons in the nucleus and that's what precipitates what would otherwise be an impossible decay?

Comment: Yes, it's a virtual W+. The overall p-p fusion reaction is exothermic, but the energy released is only 1.442 MeV, including the 1.022 MeV released by the positron-electron annihilation. I give more details here: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/48281/16685

Comment: Classically, the solar core temperature isn't high enough to give protons sufficient KE to overcome their electrostatic repulsion. Gamow showed that diproton formation requires quantum tunneling.

Comment: Lets put it this way: if two protons at rest could become a proton and neutron at rest conservation of energy would be violated because the  neutron has mass ~$939.6 MeV/c^2$ and the proton ~938.3. the defect is $1.3MeV/c^2$. Thus, in order to fuse there should be enough energy in the center of mass of the two protons to  allow energetically the reaction and release the binding energy by becoming a deuteron (irrespective of the interactions involved, just from energy considerations)

Comment: see this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positron_emission#Energy_conservation . otherwise there would be no stable nuclei.